# I can only find how to fit a smaller background to a bigger size page using I want to fit a 5000px background to the width of smaller pages

Tags: html, css, background-image, joomla3.0, background-size

I have a 5000px plus bg image which I want to use as a backgroun but I want it to fit the width.
I can only apply the CSS to the body or html. I cant add any div or any other HTML to the page.

My idea is to have a background stretch to the width of the page. If I use a 1024px width it works perfectly with a 1080P screen size but on a 2k or 4k screen the background is blurred.

So I thought let me use an image that will fit 5k screen. So that works properly but in a 1080P screen the BG is displayed at full size

The background has "header image/artwork" that is now outside the screen also it now occupies one third of the screen vertically.

I wanted it to reduce size to 1080P so the full artwork is seen and also the empty space below is seen.

I tried searching for solution and all I have seen online and on stackoverflow can ony stretch the image.

```
body {
background-image = url("myimage.jpg");
background-size = cover;
}
```

The above code does not work I can only add a css code like above to an external stylesheet.
Inline css like below I cannot add.(which works)

```
body style="background-image: url(images/backgroundchristmas1.jpg);background-size: cover;"
```

When I use the same code I have used many solutions it displays the BG in full size that 5000px it does not reduce the size to fit a 1080p screen.

I am aware of the solution that uses a div at 100% and then apply the background to the div. But I cannot edit the HTML of the page I can only add the CSS to the Body tag or html tag in a css file as it is a Joomla template

Please let me know if there is any other solution

Thanks

Comment: You can just use `background-size : cover;` ? See https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/background-size.

However, unnecessarily loading large images on small devices is a very bad practice.
You should watch how media queries works (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: Thank you for the answer I forgot to mention that this exact code does not work. I have updated my question.
When I have tried to use it with a 5000px image in a 1080p screen it does not reduce in size. It will stretch a 1200px width image to fit a 2k or 4k screen but won't reduce a bigger image. Yes I am aware but I just wanted to use a background temporarily for the Holiday season which is not big in size as it only has a header image which I want to show

Comment: For us to help on this, we will need Minimal, Reproducible Example...
See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I need to mention that background-size : cover; only works on a div. So if you put a div at 100% and then apply the background to the div the background-size : cover; works perfectly but it won't work directly to a background.  I will try to produce a minimal example also

Comment: I can't find this information in the documentation, can you provide me a source?
Here is my codepen https://codepen.io/SioGabx/pen/rNrxENO and `background-size:cover;` works on inline element...

Comment: I uploaded a blank page http://www.suratcafe.com/ You can view source and check the code I have added it inline
```
<body style="background-image: url(images/backgroundchristmas1.jpg)" background-size="cover">
</body>```

As you can see it is displaying the 4000px odd width in full size. It won't reduce the width to fit the screen size

Comment: You need to put `background-size:cover;` inside your style tag.
`<body style="background-image: url(images/backgroundchristmas1.jpg);background-size: cover;"></body>`

Comment: Thank you I can't apply inline css to my body tag I can only add css code to a custom file and it does not work that way. But it does work inline. Thank you for your time appreciate it. I think I can safely assume there is no workaround for that right?

Comment: There's no reason why it won't work with css. If so, then there must be an error in your css file.

Comment: I updated the page I have added the CSS in the head. It still does not work.

Comment: The page is probably still cached by your browser (Ctrl+F5 to refresh cache). The image is displayed correctly on my side

Comment: It works Thank you so much For your help. Appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're saying you can css body or html, so add css to the body with a background image plus a size cover

```css
body {
  background-image = url("myimage.jpg");
  background-size = cover;
}
```

check the link given by SioGabx (French), or this one https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size (english), to check other values

Comment: This works perfectly when it is applied to a div.
The page you linked has applied it to a div.
If you apply the same code to the body tag then it will "cover"(rather stretch) a smaller image like a 800px width image to fit a 1080p screen but it will not reduce the width of a bigger picture that is a 5000px width image to fit a 1080p screen.
I think this is how it works on background but I am hoping there is a workaround.

Comment: @pierfarrugia A mistake is in your css code, it's not "=" to define values of properties in css but ":"

Comment: @SioGabx, yes you're right. Sorry for the mistake, I just type the answer quite quickly. The idea was to say you can access to body property.